# Deserialise dynamic json types

Tags: json, dynamic, json.net

I want to deserialize json which returns different data for different parameters.
Mostly I get:

```
 {"posts": [{ "id" : 1, "name":"post1" },{ "id" : 1, "name":"post1" }]}
```

But sometimes the data returned is

```
{"posts": false}
```

I want to deserialize this as the following class

```
public class GetReaderResponse
{
   public IEnumerable<ReaderPost> posts {get; set;}
}

public class ReaderPost
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string name{get; set;}
}
```

I am using C#,json.net but not able to do this correctly.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetReaderResponse>(dataString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a custom converter, but an easy way to handle this would be to write an error handler that detects errors with the `posts` property:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.Error += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (string.Equals("posts", args.ErrorContext.Path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var currentObject = args.CurrentObject as GetReaderResponse;

        currentObject.posts = Enumerable.Empty<ReaderPost>();

        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
};

GetReaderResponse resp = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetReaderResponse>(json, settings);
```

This sets `posts` to `Enumerable.Empty<ReaderPost>`. This is still a little unsatisfying because if *any* error occurs, the property will be set. You could build a full custom converter to do this as a more complete solution.

Here's a converter that will take care of this:

```
public class PostsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken val = JValue.ReadFrom(reader);
        object result = null;

        if (val.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            result = val.ToObject<IEnumerable<ReaderPost>>();
        }
        else if (val.Type == JTokenType.Boolean)
        {

            result = Enumerable.Empty<ReaderPost>();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert (Type type)
    {
        return typeof(IEnumerable<ReaderPost>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.Converters = new [] { new PostsConverter() };

GetReaderResponse resp = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetReaderResponse>(json, settings);
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/i9CXwp

Answer (score 1):

By using JSON.NETs built in LINQ to JSON, you can try someting like this:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
GetReaderResponse response = new GetReaderResponse();
if (jObject["posts"] is JArray)
    response = jObject.ToObject<GetReaderResponse>();

// Do something with the response object.
```

where `json` variable is the json string you need to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class GetReaderResponse
{
    public bool posts { get; set; }
    public ReaderPost[] post { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry but I corrected a typo in the json. I get 'posts' both times. Your answer does not help.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Ilija's comment I think I might have found a answer. I did not want not use string literals so I modified my class `GetReaderResponse` to look like below:

```
public class GetReaderResponse
{
    public dynamic posts {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<ReaderPost> Posts
    {
        get
        {
             if (posts is bool )
               return new ReaderPost[0];

           return posts.ToObject<IEnumerable<ReaderPost>>();            
        }
    }
}
```

Does this sound fine or does it look messy?